# Testing with MOQ and Session State Wrapper

Tags: c#, session, testing, moq, wrapper

I'm using a Session wrapper as written below. The problem I have is when running tests the try doesn't work and it goes to the catch so session variables are never being set. I'm using Moq to create a mock Session state for my mock context. If I create a variable like:

```
Session["variable"] = "something";
```

That works fine and persists to the end of the test. Everything created for in my wrapper does not. Since the Session is somehow persisting, my theory is just that I need to figure out where it is and then put it in my catch. I don't know how to go about that though.
    public class MySession
    {
        // private constructor
        private MySession() 
        {
            id = new Random().Next(100000);
        }

```
    // Gets the current session.
    public static MySession Current
    {
        get
        {                
            MySession session = new MySession();
            try
            {
                session =
                (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];
            }
            catch
            {
                //Catch nothing
            }
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new MySession();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }

    // **** add your session properties here, e.g like this:
    public int id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you've got the wrong end of the stick in the way you've created your session wrapper. A session wrapper normally means you create a class which, in production code, passes all calls to the real session. In unit tests, it does not have a real session inside and could be a mock object. Your MySession class always needs a real session, so any test using will not be a true unit test.

You might not need to roll your own, there is a HttpSessionStateWrapper in System.Web.Abstractions you could try.

Comment: This got me a little closer to what I'm aiming for since I'm not successfully able to mock session variables, but I guess that's not really what I want. I'm marking this as the answer since it put me in the right direction and I didn't really know what I was asking for.